# Can i float to top left an a toolbar icon in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this:

[image]

But i want to float home icon to top left like:

[image]

I have this into my `menu_main.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notificaciones"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="User"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notificaciones"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="User"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_go_home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>


</menu>
```

How could i do this? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

u can use toolbar and set imageview for the icon and textview for tittle,,this a example

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTransaction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img_vireopos_icon"/>\

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:textSize="10pt"
                android:text="testing"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img_vireopos_icon"/>\


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```